# How do I load my manually generated cookies when I run Watir with Chromium?

Tags: ruby, watir

I want all the cookies I have when I open the browser manually. How do I load my manually generated cookies when I run Watir with Chromium?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add them one at a time, and you just have to make sure that the browser is on the same domain as the cookie you are adding. Check out Watir's [Cookie documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir%2FCookies:add)

Comment: The problem is the value, chrome has encrypted values. So I need do decrypt them, and pass the raw value? I think it should a better way since it's the same browser.

Comment: I just updated the cookies guide on the Watir website: http://watir.com/guides/cookies/ You can save cookies to a file and then load them back from the file if that helps. I'm not sure what to tell you about chrome encryption. The only cookies I add are with values I get from the application.